# how to convert timecode into seconds:fractions_of_a_second?

Tags: python

Given timecode in this format

```
00:00:00,0
```

What is the best way to convert this into seconds.fractions_of_a_second?

Comment: hint: 1 hour = 60 minutes and 1 minute = 60 seconds.

Comment: Looks like a SMPTE timecode as hrs, mins, secs, frames. If so, you will need the frames per second as well as JBernardo's useful constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime module is your friend in this case

```
import datetime
time_string = "17:48:12,98"
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, "%H:%M:%S,%f")
seconds = 60 * t.minute * t.hour

print (seconds, t.microsecond)
```